# Добавить префикс определенному количеству строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Добрый день. Подскажите как можно правильно добавить префикс определенному количеству строк.
Есть файл содержащий ~100к строк. Со структурой вида:

```
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         $$
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         $$  
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         $$  
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
         AAA:BBB:CCC
```

Мне нужно добавить первым 3 строкам префикс `001:`, с 3 по 6 например `007:`
с 6 по 9 `:010` Чтобы на выходе получился файл со структурой:

```
     001:AAA:BBB:CCC
     001:AAA:BBB:CCC
     001:AAA:BBB:CCC
     $$
     007:AAA:BBB:CCC
     007:AAA:BBB:CCC
     007:AAA:BBB:CCC
     $$
     010:AAA:BBB:CCC
     010:AAA:BBB:CCC
     010:AAA:BBB:CCC
```

Для одной строки использую примерно такой код:

```
    while(<IN>) 
{
    if ($. % 3 == 1){
    my $line = $_;
    print OUT "002:".$line;
    }
    }
    close IN;
    close OUT;
```

как это маштабировать использовать счетчик? Может есть возможность в Perl указать промежуток?

Comment: "Мне нужно добавить первым 3 строкам префикс 001:, с 3 по 6 например 007: с 6 по 9 :010 " в примере у Вас, с 4 по 6 приставка 007, а 010 с 7 по 9. А вообще, по какому принципу должны нумероваться строки, т.е. какая цифра будет с 10 по 12?

Comment: По тому что вы привели, вам надо дописывать числа ко всем строкам кроме `$$`. при этом когда встречаете `$$` вам надо переключить текущий номер на следующий.

Comment: @Mike Все верно Но я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, поэтому остановился на номере строки, тк количество строк в диапазоне известно.

Comment: @edem Число может быть любым но в формате xxx:.

Comment: Ну вы ведете в какой то переменной текущее число. в цикле если строка равна `$$` изменяете число и больше ничего не делаете. Иначе (строка не равна `$$`) печатаете текущее число и строку. Если вы это будете делать по номерам строк ... ну ок. но вам все равно надо делать то же самое только проверять что остаток от деления на 4 не равен какому то конкретному значению, но мне это кажется менее удобным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что требуется ...

```
my $num=1;
while(<IN>) {
 if(/\$\$/) {
  $num++;
  print OUT $_;
 } else {
  print OUT sprintf("%03d:%s",$num,$_);
 }
}
```

В `$num` номер в данный момент выводимый в строки. Операцию `++` надо заменить на ваш способ получения следующего числа (для меня осталось загадкой как получается последовательность 1, 7, 10).

Comment: Такая последовательность берется из БД по запросу.

Comment: @EvgeniyA Я думаю не составит труда брать очередное число из БД в том месте где у меня ++ стоит